# Infinite loop in useEffect, async/await in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, use-effect, react-state-management

I know this question has been asked a lot - but I need some help!

I would like `getExistingCards()` to execute and `setCards` *before* `updateActivity()`.

`getExistingCards()` should `setCards` *if* 1) cards exist, and 2) `cards` *is* an empty array 
(I don't want to setCards to `existingCards` if `cards` is already set to `existingCards`!)

The below works perfectly, so this shouldn't have to change.

```js
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    updateActivity(path, cards);
  }, [cards]);
```

Adding `getExistingCards()` below causes an infinite loop (which makes sense because I know I'm setting state within the effect, and cards is also in the dependency array):

```js
  // useLayoutEffect executes before useEffect
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const getExistingCards = () => {
      if (activity) {
        if (path.field === "activity_milestones" || path.field === "activity_indicators") {
          let existingItems = activity[path.field]
          if (existingItems) {
            setCards(existingItems);
          }
        }
      }
    };
    getExistingCards();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    updateActivity(path, cards);
  }, [cards]);
```

I also tried to add both `updateActivity()` and `getExistingCards()` to the `useEffect` implementing async/await, but realize `getExistingCards()` is not actually a promise.

Any insight would be really appreciated - thank you

Comment: `cards` is not in the dependency array of `useLayoutEffect`, right?

Comment: @Agney - correct, I only want `getExistingCards()` to execute when the page initially renders, and setCards to whatever exists (if they exist).

Comment: So what is causing the infinite loop?

Comment: Could you provide more code for your case, like what is inside `updateActivity`, where is `path` and `activity` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the length of cards before your execute your embedded function

```
  useEffect(() => {
   if (cards.length === 0) updateActivity(path, cards);
  }, [cards]);
```